# Java ADT Emulator problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having trouble setting the emulator to target Android 4.0. Since updating my Java ADT I can only choose Android 4.2.2. Some of the applications I created won't open in the new firmware/sdk. The ones that do will crash and ask to wait or close the application.

I tried downloading the SDK packages of the older versions but that screws up the program and gives me the "Your SDK version is outdated please update to 22.#####."

How can I go back to targeting 4.0?

Comment: what's the minSdK version you've set in your app ?

Comment: The older version I had went up to 4.2. So it was between 3.0-4.2 but emulator was set to 4.0.